# I keep getting npm ERR! code 1 for command react-scripts build with my code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, npm, create-react-app

I have a create-react-app app that works on my Windows 10 workstation running node v12.19.0 and npm v6.14.8. I have been able to run `npm start` and `npm run build` and access the app just fine.

While trying to deploy the same code to DigitalOcean's App Platform, and to an Ubuntu droplet, I cannot for the life of me get the app to start. I am getting the errors below when I run `npm run build`:

[Screenshot: "npm ERR! command sh -c CI=false react-scripts build"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9toi.png)

[Screenshot: "debug log at /root/.npm/_logs"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxfEc.png)

I thought it was possibly because I developed the app on Windows and some of the folders in my project may have caused issues. To test this, I used `create-react-app` again and was able to run the stock application in Ubuntu. I then put my `src` and `public` folders into the new project folder and installed the dependencies individually thinking that might help. It did not, I immediately got the error again. I just can't figure out what the exact issue is with my code.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "capstone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "d3": "^6.5.0",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "plotly.js": "1.58.4",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-plotly.js": "2.5.1",
    "react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "start": "react-scripts start"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried using a `build` value of `npm run build`, `CI= npm run build`, and `CI=false npm run build` with no luck; all the same error. I also get the same error with `npm start`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried not to use SO for any of this project so far, but this one has taken up too much of my time.

Comment: Based on the message referring to you running out of memory, upgrading to a beefier droplet or enabling swap on it would help.

Comment: This error specifically was caused by as bad package, but I ended up upgrading for TensorFlow anyway. I ran out of memory very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It turns out this is specifically due to the `plotly.js` package (not `react-plotly.js`). I individually uninstalled one package at a time until and it finally started up after removing plotly. I found a GitHub issue for this and someone had a resolution: https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js/issues/135

To get it working, you can use `react-plotly.js` and `plotly.js-basic-dist` with a little work around mentioned by @francesco-hayes in the comments.